# AngularJS valor $scope fora da view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

estou com um dúvida no angularJs que não estou conseguindo resolver, o meu `index.html` é o seguinte:

```
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
<div ng-show="success" class="alert alert-success">{{success}}</div>

<div class="content">
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Para atribuir valor nessas views eu normalmente faria o seguinte:

```
if (response.data.success) {
   $scope.success = response.data.success;
} else if (response.data.error) {
   $scope.error = response.data.error;
}
```

só que definindo o valor da `$scope.error` ou `$scope.success`, o valor não é exibido (acho que deve ser por causa da `div` estar fora da `partial`), ele só é exibido quando eu atribuo o valor na `$rootScope`, porém o valor continua sendo exibido até haver algum redirecionamento, ele não é limpo quando é executada alguma requisição ajax (o automático do angular).

Mas resumindo, minha pergunta é, há alguma maneira de exibir o valor da `$scope` fora da `partial`? se não, como que eu faço para limpar o valor da `$rootScope` sem ter que atualizar a página?

Comment: o `$scope.error` é um string? porque o `ng-show` tem que receber uma expressão para saber se exibe ou não.

Comment: Em comparações booleanas, o javascript considera qualquer valor não nulo como `true`, como vc pode ver no trecho de código a seguir:

```var teste = "teste";
   if (teste) { 
      alert(teste); 
   } ```

Comment: Dei uma olhada por cima no seu código e não vi um controller pro index.html, talvez seja esse o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o ngRoute? poderia por gentileza enviar seu código de exemplo completo?

Talvez lhe ajude https://jsfiddle.net/willtamagi/ng12enmL/3/

EDITED

Talvez utilizando Factory te ajude amigo, segue um exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/willtamagi/krced2sd/3/

Abraços

Comment: Sim, eu estou utilizando o ngRoute, vou colocar os códigos e depois atualizo a pergunta.

Comment: A aplicação está no repositório: https://github.com/dennis90/cotacaoweb/tree/master/web
(o que importa está nos arquivos: modules/authentication/controller.js , scripts/app.js e index.html)
quanto ao trecho de código, é muito interessante, mas não é bem o que eu estou procurando, eu estou querendo "injetar" aquele trecho de código (as divs com as mensagens de erro e de sucesso) em todas as partials do projeto... no trecho de código que vc forneceu, eu teria que redirecionar para uma view separada...

Comment: Veja a resposta atualizada, talvez lhe ajude. Abraço

Comment: Como o Maicon comentou de qualquer forma você vai precisar de um controller em alguma das divs superiores as divs de error e success no seu index.html